# Block certain email providers using Regex

Tags: php, regex, cakephp, email-validation

Please dont downvote the question because of the fact that the answer Im looking for is not an anser someone should pursue. I'm fully aware of that, but it's not my idea, I just have to deliver :D

In cakephp, I have the following dataentry in my model:

```
    'email' => array(
        'email' => array(
            'rule' => array('email',false,'(^[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$)')
        ),
    )
```

The email rule is a common function in cakephp data validation, and the second and third parameter are optional. The third being the regex. I wasnt happy with the given regex string so I added my own. Now I want to exclude Gmail, Hotmail and yahoo addresses.

How can I change the Regular Expression so those addresses are producing false as result? I cant get it right.

Comment: Why do you want to piss off users?

Comment: Well great question: I dont and it breaks my heart. Its just that the guy who wants this thing thinks that it filters out the people that just want to have a look at his tool while not leaving behind a real email to identify em by.

Comment: Just a hint: I'm pretty sure that you can have a much more *interesting* e-mail address than what your regex matches.

Comment: Then create a validation system to allow access. Whatever email address they provide, send an email with a link they have to click to allow them to gain access. Once they click the link, always allow that email address access.

Comment: Tell your customer people will just start using throwaway mail addresses if they cannot use the real one. Actually, for "just having a look" I'd use such an email address anyway.

Comment: @Piskvor I agree... the given RegEx would reject my perfectly valid address, which has a single character as the user part. It also doesn't allow for the plus sign `+` and other valid non-alpha characters. @Has Wassink I would suggest you read over [this page on RegEx for matching email addresses](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html).

Comment: @ewall: There is one good thing said on that page, and it's not a regex: "Regexes Don’t Send Email" - in other words, "you don't really know whether an address is valid until you try to send an email to it"; [so relying on a regex for reliable detection is pointless]. Other than that, the author himself freely admits that the regexes presented are merely *good enough* for his specific purposes.

Comment: Admittedly, I tl;dr-ed it by looking for the bolded parts :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why on earth would you want to exclude gmail, hotmail and yahoo addresses? There are plenty of people who only have one of these addresses and no other. This is a bad idea. If you are target a specific "audience" I'd suggest making a list of allowed domains instead.

Anyway, here's a functional regex for you which is shorter than the one you already have.. try it out:

```
\b[\w\.-]+@((?!gmail|googlemail|yahoo|hotmail).)[\w\.-]+\.\w{2,4}\b
```

Comment: Fully agree, but the customer wants it this way :) So I just want to know if it's possible. My regular expressions only reach so far...

Comment: This did the Trick Serrghi... Thanks! Im awfully sorry for dragging you through hell to get my answer :D

Comment: No problem :) If you mark my answer as the Accepted answer that would be thank enough! :)

Comment: This won't really work in case of uppercase

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a regex for this.

The proper solution is to `explode()` the email address at the `@` sign and then use plain string comparisons or even `in_array()` to check if the domain is blacklisted.

Comment: But is it possible? I wouldve never done it this way, but I want to use the tools given to me by cakephp, not add my own functions. This way I can keep my model clean.

Comment: [explode is a built-in function in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), so it should work in any PHP framework, I should hope.